# No feedback when I run the crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import re


def get_one_page(url):
    try:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        return None
    except RequestException:
        return None


def parse_one_page(html):
    pattern = re.compile('<dd>.*?board-index.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?src="(.*?)".*?name.*?a.*?>(.*?)</ a>.*?star.*?>(.*?)</p>'
                         '.*?releasetime.*?(.*?)</p>.*?integer.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?fraction.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?</dd>', re.S)
    items = re.findall(pattern, html)
    return items


def main():
    url = 'https://maoyan.com/board/4'
    html = get_one_page(url)
    print(parse_one_page(html))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: This is a screenshot]

Just following the tutorial,but nothing back.I didn't find that there was a error,but it happened. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see. Possible issues:

1. Your function get_one_page might be silently returning `None`
   through the first `return None` statement. You could set a print
   this way to check what are you actually getting

   ```
   def main():
       url = 'https://maoyan.com/board/4'
       html = get_one_page(url)
       print(html)
       print(parse_one_page(html))
   ```
2. Your function parse_one_page might not find anything and return an empty list. With the previous print we set for `html` you should be able to see the if that's the case.

How would I slightly edit these functions:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
import re


def get_one_page(url):
    try:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return "Success", response.text
        return "Failure", None
    except RequestException:
        return "Failure", None


def parse_one_page(html):
    pattern = re.compile('<dd>.*?board-index.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?src="(.*?)".*?name.*?a.*?>(.*?)</ a>.*?star.*?>(.*?)</p>'
                         '.*?releasetime.*?(.*?)</p>.*?integer.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?fraction.*?>(.*?)</i>.*?</dd>', re.S)
    items = re.findall(pattern, html)
    return items


def main():
    url = 'https://maoyan.com/board/4'
    result, html = get_one_page(url)
    if result == "Success":
        items = parse_one_page(html)
        if items: #If list is empty, this equals False. Else, it equals True
            print(items)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If there's a bigger context you could let us know I could advise you better on how to improve it. If its just a simple script to do a quick scrap, I guess this will do.